# Easiest way to draw a rectangular grid in HTML/JS inside div element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a simple user interface that would allow users to stack sudoku puzzles on top of each other. So far the rough look of the interface is something like this.

[image]

I would now like to implement the logic that would allow me to generate a sudoku grid inside the white rectangle  (div) on the right. If the user for example enters cols 4 and rows 4, it has to generate a 4x4 rectangle that looks like this (but smaller of course :) ):

[image]

Once a grid like that would be inside of that square, i'd want to make it possible for user to drag it onto the grey div area on the left. But when you do that, the one inside a white rectangle should remain (so basically when you drag that square you drag a clone of it onto the left side - so that you can after grab additional grids from the white square and stack as many of them as you wish on the left.

It would also probably best to have a large grid on the grey area so that you can align the squares you drag there (clipping isn't necessary). All the advices are welcome!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: easiest way would be with div's, each square = 1 new div that is float left and with the specified dimensions, all those div's reside in a wrapper that is your sudoko grid.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in jQuery a little while back. It may need adapting to suit your needs but essentially it creates a grid of any size.

```
// HTML elements

var game_element = $('.game'); // Main game html
var grid_parent = $('.grid');
var grid_section = $('.grid_section')
var grid_parent_html = '<div class="grid"></div>';
var grid_section_html = 'grid_section';

/**
* CREATE THE GRID. Function loops through section count and appends the
* neccessary components with correct widths in relation to the screen size.
**/

function create_grid(horizontal,vertical){

    // Set the height and widths of the grid sections
    p_width = 100 / horizontal + '%';
    p_height = 100 / vertical + '%';

    // Loop through required sections and append to our main grid
    for(i = 0; i < horizontal * vertical; i++){
        grid_parent.append(
            '<div style="width:' + 
            p_width + ';height:' + p_height + '" class="' + 
            grid_section_html + '"></div>'
        );
    }
    section_total = horizontal * vertical;
}


create_grid(4,4);
```

and a little bit of CSS

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
    height:100vh;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    .grid_holder{
        padding:50px;
        height:100vh;
        .grid{
            height:100%;
            &_section{
                float:left;
                box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 1px black inset;
                padding:10px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see a working example here http://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/a4134449d800430fafedce13122f207a